# Recursive CopyConstr. - Linked List

Tags: c++, recursion, visual-c++, linked-list, copy-constructor

First of all, this is part of practice on Linked Lists and recursion. I'm trying to create a copy constructor that recursively deep copies a given LinkedList. I have coded the LinkedList methods already.

Problems I run into: it seems to be copying correctly during recursive calls, but fails to print afterwards. I believe either the list was not properly returned or  a new list is being created every time. Definitely there is problem linking to the head, the list exists somewhere but head doesn't point to it?

Here's the necessary parts of the LinkedList.h file:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList* list1)
{

if (list1 == NULL) { 
    std::cout << "End of Loop";
    return;
}

listLength = 0;
node newHead;
copy(list1->head,&newHead); // Start copy constructing 
}

void LinkedList::copy(const node * p1, node* p2)
{

if (p1 == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Copy Finished";
}

else { 
    node* p2 = new node;

    p2->artist = p1->artist;
    std::cout << p2->artist << "\t";
    p2->song = p1->song;
    std::cout << p2->song << "\n";

    listLength++;
     copy(p1->next,p2->next);

}

}
```

[original list print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVYTj.png)

[copied list - output correct while copying but print method fails?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej6FT.png)

ListLength of copied list is correct but no output??

Comment: Why don't you implement the three/five copy-control members instead of self-defined constructor and member functions? I would suggest you read Ch. 13 in *C++ Primer* if you don't know what are copy-control members.

Comment: `LinkedList::copy` doesn't use its `p2` parameter, instead hiding it by a local variable with the same name. `newHead` is never updated. And even if it were - it's a local variable that's never used for anything. The end result of all those gyrations is this: a bunch of nodes is allocated on the heap but never linked to anything - they are all leaked. `this->head` of the new `LinkedList` instance remains uninitialized.

Comment: Note also that `LinkedList(const LinkedList* list1)` is not in fact a copy constructor. `LinkedList(const LinkedList& list1)` would have been a copy constructor.

Comment: In the structure `node`, what are the type of `artist` and `song` ? Could you provide the complete definition of `struct node` and `class LinkedList` ?